# Would a twin-planet system necessarily be tidally locked?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics

I'm creating a short story about two planets, roughly the same mass, orbiting around each other somewhat like the Earth and the Moon. Would it be possible for both to also be rotating at the same time, or would they both lock onto each other like the Moon does with Earth?

Comment: to conserve angular momentum(assuming both planets having different rotation speed initially), as time passes each planet applies "braking" and "boosting" on one another rotation resulting in a phenomenon as tidal locking.

Answer (score 4):

Any two objects that orbit one another are in fact exchanging energy with each other (via gravitational acceleration). Since all systems move towards equilibrium, all (two-body) orbits would eventually enter tidal lock. In fact the Earth is slowly tidally locking to the Sun as it orbits, however this process will take billions of years.

To answer the thrust of your question:

No, it's not necessary that a two-body system be instantly tidally locked, however it *is* necessary that it eventually tidally lock.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually (given enough time) any system of orbiting bodies will tidally lock. The more massive the objects, or the closer they are, the sooner the tidal locking will happen, but it will happen eventually, regardless of the objects, because tidal forces will occur to some extent.

However, you do not need to worry about that. All that matters is for the planets to be far enough away from each other that they are not tidally locked to each other when the story happens.

If the exact distance is not important to your story, then you can just say that the two planets are not tidally locked because they are far enough away. However, if the exact distance is necessary, it just becomes a problem of picking a far enough distance that they don't tidally lock.